# onCreate called after onActivityResult when I pick picture from gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I have 'SherlockFragmentActivity' with overrided 'onActivityResult'.

I try to get image from camera and gallery and crop it.
The problem is I returned on my activity not fragment after onActivityResult called.

```
...
            FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            LogInFragment logFrag = new LogInFragment();
            t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, logFrag);
            t.commit();
...
     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:background="@color/textWhite"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I also have 'SherlockFragment' where I picked image:

```
startImagePickerDialog(this);


public void startImagePickerDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getSherlockActivity());
        myAlertDialog.setTitle("Upload Pictures Option");
        myAlertDialog.setMessage("How do you want to set your picture?");

        myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // call android default gallery
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // ******** code for crop image
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                            "Complete action using"), Const.GALLERY_PICTURE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ActivityNotFoundException");
                }
            }
        });
        myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                // call android default camera
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, Const.CAMERA_REQUEST);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ActivityNotFoundException");
                }
            }
        });
        myAlertDialog.show();
    }
```

And 'onActivityResult' in 'SherlockFragment':

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != getSherlockActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "resultCode != RESULT_OK");
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == Const.CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST");
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "extras != null");
                Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                icon.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == Const.GALLERY_PICTURE) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE");
            Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
            if (extras2 != null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "extras != null");
                Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");
                icon.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
When I call camera activity my main activity call 'onSaveInstanceState' and after that 'onRestoreInstanceState'. Is it a reason?

Answer (score 12):

1. Check your "Settings" -> "Developer options" -> "Don't keep activities" flag.
2. This is the nature of android if your device needs memory it destroys activities which are not visible. So you have to consider that your activity can be recreated any time. BTW "Don't keep activities" option is there to simulate your application when your device needs memory and destroys your backstack activities.

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment. Android 4.0 and greater devices have an option called Don't keep activities. If it is selected on a device then your backstack activities are going to be destroyed and recreated. Just check your test device and be sure that it is not the reason of your problem.

Comment: @aegean charming solution

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine, but what if this option enabled? any other solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

Change

```
Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
```

To

```
Bitmap photo=(Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
```

**Edited:-**

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult");
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode != getSherlockActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "resultCode != RESULT_OK");
                return;
            }

            if (requestCode == Const.CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST");
                Bitmap photo=(Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");// Changed Here
                icon.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }

            if (requestCode == Const.GALLERY_PICTURE) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "requestCode == GALLERY_PICTURE");
               Uri imageUri= intent.getData();// Changed Here, or first decode the image to Avoid OutOfMemory Error
               icon.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The problem in other not in getting image.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
frag.startActivityForResult(...);
```

In your fragment with

```
startActivityForResult(...)
```