# Activity recreating before getting a resultant url after capturing a picture In redmi Note 4

Tags: android, android-fragments, activity-lifecycle

I have one activity and multiple fragments.Here my use case is I have to capture an image using  from one of the fragment,the resultant image will shown in an ImageView in that fragment.But here the problem is the fragment destroying its view and activity was recreating again.How can I show the resultant image in that fragment ? This problem occuring only in RedmiNote4.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
cameraBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//check permissions
if(hasPermission){
        values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Image File name");
mCapturedImageURI =getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
intentPicture.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
if(intentPicture.resolveActivity(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(intentPicture,CAMERA_REQUEST);
}

    }
}
});




    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        } else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST ){

            Uri uri =mCapturedImageURI;

       //setImage
           loadImage(uri)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also RedmiNote4 user.

[With this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19690491/8159810) I was facing that issue.

When I turn off flag "Don't keep activities" It solved my issue after digging solution for 2 days.

Comment: " Don't keep activities" flag was in disable mode only,anyway thanks.

Comment: @LakshmiPriyaVikram your code is working perfectly on my device..

How are you loading image in image view?

I have used **Glide**  load image as below :       

'Uri uri =mCapturedImageURI;

            Glide.with(this).load(uri)
                    .error(R.drawable.bg_gray).into(img);'